# Parsing JSON in shell script with regex

Tags: json, shell

I need to parse the jsonarray by using regex. My json is

```
"keys": [
      {
        "host": "example.com"       
      },
      {
        "host": "example.net"
      }
    ]
```

I need to get the two hosts values.

Comment: If it were proper json (e.g., wrapped in `{}`); you could use [`jq -r '.keys[] | .host'`](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you want to extract text, `grep` is your friend:

```
grep -Po '(?<="host": ")[^"]*' myjsonFile
```

For example:

```
kent$  echo '"keys": [
      {
        "host": "example.com"       
      },
      {
        "host": "example.net"
      }
    ]'|grep -Po '(?<="host": ")[^"]*'

example.com
example.net
```

Comment: Could you add more explanation to this anwser?

Comment: @Andy it needs gnu grep.

Answer (score 1):

The following regex will grab your host values using a non-greedy kleene wildcard:

```
/"host":\s"(.*?)"/
```